# setInterval(...) is not responding to decrease in viewport height

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, caching, resize

**Scenario**

I've set up three simple web pages whose content should always remain both vertically and horizontally centered on the browser's viewport in spite of changes in the size of the viewport in between page refreshes. I used W3C.org's entry ["Centering Things"](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center#vertical) for help on horizontal and vertical centering. I'm testing the code in both Chrome and Safari with the help of their developer tools.

**Problem**

When I load the index.php page, the page content is initially centered, as it ought to be. When I change the width or horizontal value of the viewport, the browser responds by continually re-centering the page content horizontally. And when I *increase* the height or vertical value of the viewport, the browser also responds by continually re-centering the page content vertically--so far so good. But when I *decrease* the height of the viewport, the height of the body element does not change, and the page content remains fixed at the last vertical position at which the value of the height of the body element was its largest.

The more the height of the viewport is diminished, the greater the *scrollable portion* of the page and its content become (there ought to be no scrollable portion at all). [If you were to refresh the page, however, you would find the page content to be re-centered on the current viewport dimensions. The problem only arises so long as you do not refresh the page and then attempt to decrease the height of the viewport.] Upon increasing the height of the viewport again, the page content remains fixed until the value of the height of the viewport matches and surpasses the value of the height of the body element, at which point the browser responds by continually re-centering the page content vertically, as it ought to do.

I haven't had any encounters with this kind of problem until now despite having implemented this sort of construct on multiple occasions previously. Before I encountered this problem, I was experiencing a different frustration with the browser. The browser was not reflecting the changes made to the CSS, at which point I bypassed the browser's cache. I was able to get around the frustration, but its ramifications may have some relation to the current problem.

**.js for all three pages**

Updated .js

```
$(function() {



var viewportWidth = $( window ).width();
var viewportHeight = $( window ).height();
$( "body" ).css({
    width: viewportWidth,
    height: viewportHeight
});

$( window ).resize(function() {

    viewportWidth = $( window ).width();
    viewportHeight = $( window ).height();
    $( "body" ).css({
        width: viewportWidth,
        height: viewportHeight
    });

});



});
```

Original .js

```
$(function() {



var viewportWidth = $( window ).width();
var viewportHeight = $( window ).height();

$( "body" ).css({
    width: viewportWidth,
    height: viewportHeight
});

setInterval(function() {

    viewportWidth = $( window ).width();
    viewportHeight = $( window ).height();

    $( "body" ).css({
        width: viewportWidth,
        height: viewportHeight
    });

}, 10);



});
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Interactive | Home</title>
    <link href="css/laptop-index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="register"><a href="pages/register.php">Register</a></div>
        <div id="login"><a href="pages/login.php">Login</a></div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jsindex.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.php's CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative
}

#container {
    position: absolute;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#container div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1pt solid black
}
    #register {
        margin-right: 50px
    }

    #register:hover, #login:hover {
        background-color: #AAFFFF
    }
        #container div a {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none
        }
            #container div a:hover {
                color: blue
            }
```

**register.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Interactive | Registration</title>
    <link href="../css/laptop-register.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" id="form" method="post">
        <input name="my_firstname" placeholder="Your first name" type="text">
        <input name="my_lastname" placeholder="Your last name" type="text">
        <br>
        <input name="my_address" placeholder="Your street address" type="text">
        <input name="my_address" placeholder="Your street address continued" type="text">
        <input name="my_city" placeholder="Your city" type="text">
        <input name="my_state" placeholder="Your state" type="text">
        <input name="my_zip" placeholder="Your zip" type="text">
        <input name="my_country" placeholder="Your country" type="text">
        <br>
        <input name="my_phone" placeholder="Your phone number" type="tel">
        <input name="my_email" placeholder="Your email" type="text">
        <br>
        <input name="my_username" placeholder="Your username" type="text">
        <input name="my_password" placeholder="Your password" type="password">
        <br>
        <textarea cols="50" name="my_message" placeholder="Your message" rows="5" type="text"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="register">
    </form>

    <div id="back_button"><a href="../index.php">Return to Home Page</a></div>

    <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/register.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Interactive | Login</title>
    <link href="../css/laptop-login.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]" id="form" method="post">
        <input name="my_username" placeholder="Your username" type="text">
        <input name="my_password" placeholder="Your password" type="password">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>

    <div id="back_button"><a href="../index.php">Return to Home Page</a></div>

    <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/login.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**register.php's and login.php's CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative
}

#form {
    position: absolute;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

#back_button a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none
}
#back_button a:hover {
    color: blue
}
```

Comment: You should really consider binding a 'resize' event handler to the window to handle for the browser window resizing, not running an interval **every 10 ms**.  That's overkill.

Comment: Can you please convert your sample to a snippit and provide the CSS you are using? My first reaction is that you should not need to make any calculations in JavaScript at all.

Comment: I've updated the .js file to include jQuery's .resize() handler instead of the setInterval() timer, but my original problem persists. @Taplar

Comment: I've updated the .js file to include jQuery's .resize() handler instead of the setInterval() timer, but my original problem persists. @ochi

Comment: I've included the .css files. @msanford

Answer (score 1):

You should really just use CSS for this, as this is exactly what CSS is for. Check out [this great guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) on how to center stuff in CSS.

You also might want to use the “vh” and “vw” unit in CSS for sizing stuff based on the viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

Y'all are right, I don't need any JS at all. In fact, the JS was actually causing the problem. Leaving the JS and altering the CSS (below) caused other strange things to happen. I'm not sure why I thought I needed to rely on it for continual horizontal and vertical centering, so I scrapped it entirely. After messing around with it a bit, this is the minimum CSS I can get away with:

```
body-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

All of the following also seem to work prepended to the above:

```
body { height: 100% }
```

,

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative
}
```

,

```
html { height: 100% }
```

,

```
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100% }
```

,

```
html { height: 100% }
body {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative
}
```